# apt-get install is not working in WSL

Tags: ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, apt, ubuntu-18.04

Windows 10 Ubuntu bash failing to install packages. Whenever I try install new package with below command, getting same error.

```
root@VASI-HOME-PC:/mnt/c/Users/vadap# apt-get install atom
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package atom
```

This is not just with atom pacakge but i tried installing other packages like pip as well and received same error.

Comment: The error message you received, indicates Atom is required, which means the package you are trying to install has a GUI.  That isn't going to be supported by WSl out of the box.  In other words, you are not going to be able to install any package, that requires Atom.

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried to install pip and few other packages. I have received the same error. Does it mean all of them had GUI ?

Comment: I'm having this issue on WSL2 Debian 10, trying to install `openssh-server` as root user. I think the issue the OP had was that he was invoking `apt` as the root user, and not sudoing from an unprivileged user. I'm not sure why, but `apt` only works when you run it with sudo from a non-root user...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Executed below 2 commands and then I was able to install the packages.

```
sudo apt update    
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Source -  https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18.04/

Comment: This answer is unlikely to be well recieved, unless you provide the relevant information from the link, like what you actually did in the body of the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Ramhound . I have updated the steps executed and later I was able to install the packages like pip.

Comment: After `update` do `apt upgrade` to be updated.

Comment: I just `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade` like Timo said and that was enough for me to get it to work.

Comment: Current wording suggests you need `python3-pip`, but you don't - running `sudo apt update` is enough.

Answer (score 10):

System: Windows 10 Enterprise, Ubuntu Windows Subsystem for Linux.

I ran this command:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

I had this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package dos2unix
```

I then ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

and it installed properly.

Answer (score 8):

This fixed it perfectly for me:
https://sundarnarasiman.net/2021/05/15/wsl2-apt-update-not-working/

Reposting incase the link ever dies:

Step #1.

On the Ubuntu distro, create a file at this location /etc/wsl.conf.

The file should have the following configuration.

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

If we don’t set this file, WSL will automatically load a default /etc/resolv.conf with default namesever configuration.

Shut down and restart the distro.

Step #2

Delete the default /etc/resolv.conf file.

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
```

Create a new /etc/resolv.conf with the following entry.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Now, restart the WSL2 and open the distro again. The apt update on WSL2 should work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

What was working for me:

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu-18.04 2
```

or

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Same error, solved after:

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list # add source
sudo apt update # update source cache
```

My sources.list file:

```
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://mirrors.163.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security multiverse
```

Edit this list according  to your location, as some sources may not apply globally.

Comment: What did you add to the ``sources.list`` file? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott File content added ;D

Answer (score -1):

### Easiest solution for Non GUI packages installation in a fresh WSL

Just run the below commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install your-package-name
```

The error is generally observed when you have a **fresh WSL** configuration on windows. Thus, you need to update your `apt-get` package manager. However, as mentioned above, for packages that involve a GUI (Atom), it isnt supported by WSL out of the box.

Answer (score -2):

Usually only updates packages is needed before:

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: This is exactly the same thing that the accepted answer already says.  Do you have additional information to add?